# Is it possible to get information about an NPM package via ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, npm

For example, the information you can see here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react
?
Package name, description, version etc. or can this only be read using "npm info "?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `https://registry.npmjs.org/PACKAGE_NAME` (for example [lodash](https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash)) to get a JSON blob information of the package.

Comment: Access to fetch at 'https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash' from origin 'https://null.jsbin.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.